# I can't create the banner area the way I want. How can I do it?

Tags: html, css, frontend

They asked me to edit the banner area. My intern and frontend knowledge is not very good. The banners in the photo I posted below are two separate photos. I have to fit the pictures of the products at the same value and give a separate link to each photo. But I couldn't create the layout in my head and I don't know how to do it. I would be very grateful if you could give an idea.

This is the order that should be:
[image: this is how it used to be]

This is how I did it:

[image]

Here, it is necessary to put the photos of the products separately and go to the separate links when they come to the top. I can make no problem with them, but I couldn't make the order in this way. Currently, there are two photos in total, so they are not separate products, they are all one picture. I would be very grateful if you could give me an idea how to do this.

**HTML code:**

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<link href="~/Content/bscarousel.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/Scripts/Home/Slider.js"></script>

<div ng-controller="SliderController">
    <div>
 <table border="0" bordercolor="#aaa" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="background-color:#4C8C9E;">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <a href="https://www.arkadasgrup.com/ListeArama/311/Seri">
                            <img class="img-responsive" src="~/images/ShamanKing.jpg" width="60%" height="120px;" /><p style="color:white;">Shaman King</p>
                        </a>
                    </td>
                      .
                      .
                      .
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I organize all the photos? I'm trying to make them all the same size but I couldn't.

Css:

```
.carousel {
  position: relative;
}

.carousel-inner {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.carousel-item {
  position: relative;
  display: none;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  @include transition($carousel-transition);
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  perspective: 1000px;
}

.carousel-item.active,
.carousel-item-next,
.carousel-item-prev {
  display: block;
}

.carousel-item-next,
.carousel-item-prev {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}


.carousel-item-next.carousel-item-left,
.carousel-item-prev.carousel-item-right {
  transform: translateX(0);

  @supports (transform-style: preserve-3d) {
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
}

.carousel-indicators {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 15;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding-left: 0; // override <ol> default
  margin-right: $carousel-control-width;
  margin-left: $carousel-control-width;
  list-style: none;

  li {
    position: relative;
    flex: 0 1 auto;
    width: $carousel-indicator-width;
    height: $carousel-indicator-height;
    margin-right: $carousel-indicator-spacer;
    margin-left: $carousel-indicator-spacer;
    text-indent: -999px;
    background-color: rgba($carousel-indicator-active-bg, .5);

    &::before {
      position: absolute;
      top: -10px;
      left: 0;
      display: inline-block;
      width: 100%;
      height: 10px;
      content: "";
    }
    &::after {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: -10px;
      left: 0;
      display: inline-block;
      width: 100%;
      height: 10px;
      content: "";
    }
  }

  .active {
    background-color: $carousel-indicator-active-bg;
  }
}

.carousel-caption {
  position: absolute;
  right: ((100% - $carousel-caption-width) / 2);
  bottom: 20px;
  left: ((100% - $carousel-caption-width) / 2);
  z-index: 10;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  color: $carousel-caption-color;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: The HTML code does not correspond with the CSS code

Comment: Plus I don't really get what you even want to begin with. _"I have to fit the pictures of the products at the same value"_ - what "products", what "values"? Massively unclear what you are even talking about here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very hard to understand your question/problem given that there is no reproducible code.

If your aim is to display multiple items side by side with even spacing, you can do it like this:

HTML:

```
<div class="items">
  <img src="...">
  <img src="...">
  ...
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.items {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly; /* this gives even space between items as shown in your image in the question */
}

.items img {
  width: 100px; /* you may want to define a fixed with here so that they all look the same */
}
```

Comment: Yes, unfortunately, I couldn't explain my question fully, it was confusing, but the code you wrote really worked for me, thank you very much.